# Как работать со QSpacerItem

Tags: qt

Сделал вот такой код:

```
resize(800, 600);

QWidget *headerWidget = new QWidget;
headerWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color: #fff;");

QStackedWidget *test = new QStackedWidget;

QVBoxLayout *centralVBoxLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
centralVBoxLayout->addWidget(headerWidget);
centralVBoxLayout->addWidget(test);
centralVBoxLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget;
setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
centralWidget->setLayout(centralVBoxLayout);

QLineEdit *searchLineEdit = new QLineEdit;
searchLineEdit->setFixedSize(100, 30);

QSpacerItem *vS = new QSpacerItem(50, 10, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding); //Spacer


QHBoxLayout *headerHBoxLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
headerHBoxLayout->addWidget(searchLineEdit);


headerWidget->setLayout(headerHBoxLayout);
headerHBoxLayout->addSpacerItem(vS);
```

Проблема заключается в том как работать со Spacer'оми я хочу сделать горизонтальный спэйсер который должен сдвигать lineEdit в лево, но у меня получилось что он вертикальный...[image: -]

Comment: А попробуйте вместо `headerHBoxLayout->addSpacerItem(vS);` попробовать `headerHBoxLayout->addStretch();`

Comment: Не это уже колхоз(костыль)

Comment: Не соглашусь: если это работает и позволяет меньше кода написать, получив тот же результат, то не костыль. Плюс, в самой документации написано что вместо QSpacerItem лучше использовать addStretch и подобные ему методы (они и так QSpacerItem используют): http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspaceritem.html#details "Normally, you don't need to use this class directly. Qt's built-in layout managers provide the following functions for manipulating empty space in layouts:". Еще считаете `addStretch` костылем? :)

Comment: В методе 'addWidget()' можно задать сразу стреч фактор и в какой части слоя будет распологаться виджет.